# Install docker parallel to LAMP

Tags: docker, lamp

I think about installing a docker system on my local test server with ubuntu 16.04. I already installed lamp with  many test applications. 
Can I use docker with mysql, apache and php parallel on the same server without compromising the already installed and used system or do i have to set up a virtual box system before?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely install Docker with all the lamp stack as containers, and that will not affect the already running apps.

You will only have to remap the docker container ports to custom ports 
(ex: apache `80->8080`)